# Master Data Business Rules Protecting Column from Edit / Change

Tags: master-data-services

I am in need of some help with Microsoft Master Data - specifically the *Business Rules*.
I am inserting data into MDS and then the users will update additional info using the excel plugin.

The data Im inserting is used in my join for reporting. 
I do not want any user to "Accidentally" change one of my inserted columns only add the data they are supposed to.

for reference - Inserting into MDS
https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2013/2/16/importing-data-into-master-data-services-2012-part-2.html

https://www.mattmasson.com/2013/06/bulk-loading-into-mds-using-ssis/

So I would  like to know how to create the MDS business rule to protect a column from being edited. The Business Rules are not intuitive to use.

You get three options to edit

**IF**

**THEN**

**ELSE**

How can I say - Do not Edit this column? :)

I have tried the following:

**IF** "Platform" has changed 
**then** "Platform" Defaults to "Platform"
**else** "Platform Defaults to Platform"

I get the following error
*"The Sequence must be greater than Zero"*

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - So I found the Answer. 
You don't do this via the Business Rules.

In the MDS web interface
Security > Manage Users or Manage Groups

You can give a person / a Group 
Read create update or delete permissions on models down to Attributes.

Thank you